# Troubleshooting item loaders between callbacks

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, web-crawler

In order to understand the "Naive approach" example in http://oliverguenther.de/2014/08/almost-asynchronous-requests-for-single-item-processing-in-scrapy/

I am trying to replicate that code. The idea is to have a single item populated where each of the fields are sourced from a different website.

I am trying to understand why I get the following behavior from the below code when I run it and I export the result  into a csv file using `scrapy crawl compSpider -o prices.csv`.

The code actually populates the nic_price with the relevant price but it doesn't do the same with the tester_price.

I believe it should do so as the item loader object is passed in the request meta field from the first callback [firstRequest], where the item loader object is created, to the second call back [parseDescription1], where the item loader object is finally loaded into an item.

I have tested that the css selectors work. Can someone please help me understand why am I getting that behaviour?

### ITEM DECLARATION

```
import scrapy
class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):       
    nic_price = scrapy.Field()
    tester_price = scrapy.Field()
```

### SPIDER CODE

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from comparator.items import ProductItem


class Compspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "compSpider"


    #start_urls = (  'https://www.shop.niceic.com/',   )

    def start_requests(self):  

        yield Request(
            'https://www.shop.niceic.com/6559-megger-mft1711-multifunction-tester-1008-121',  callback=self.firstRequest)


    def firstRequest(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), response=response)
        l.add_css('nic_price', 'div.product-info p.product-price span[itemprop="price"]::text')

        yield Request('https://www.tester.co.uk/test-safe-pen-co-meter', meta={'loader' : l}, callback= self.parseDescription1)

    def parseDescription1(self, response):

        # Recover item(loader)
        l = response.meta['loader']

        # Use just as before
        l.add_css('tester_price', 'div.price-breakdown div.price-excluding-tax span.price::text')

        yield l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I faced the same issue. Tried using both approaches, but each one has big drawback:

1. passing item loaders and using `add_value()` introduced problem of double process the value (by input and output processors), which makes it much harder to design those processors which makes code harder to read and maintain.
2. passing items instead of item loaders just kills whole idea of ItemLoaders and also introduce inconsistency throughout the code.

What I've found looking through scrapy's `scrapy.loader.ItemLoader` source (very small and simple code out there, btw) is it's `parent` keyword argument which allows you to pass parent ItemLoader and copy all of its values to new ItemLoader.

Here is the modified `parseDescription1`:

```py
def parseDescription1(self, response):

    # Recover item(loader)
    loader = response.meta['loader']

    if response.body:
        loader = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), response=response, parent=loader)

        # Use just as before
        tester_loader.add_css('tester_price', 'div.price-breakdown div.price-excluding-tax span.price::text')

    yield loader.load_item()
```

`scrapy crawl` result:

```py
2016-11-01 10:48:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.shop.niceic.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-11-01 10:48:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.shop.niceic.com/6559-megger-mft1711-multifunction-tester-1008-121> (referer: None)
2016-11-01 10:48:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tester.co.uk/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-11-01 10:48:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tester.co.uk/test-safe-pen-co-meter> (referer: https://www.shop.niceic.com/6559-megger-mft1711-multifunction-tester-1008-121)
2016-11-01 10:48:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.tester.co.uk/test-safe-pen-co-meter>
{'nic_price': [u'\xa3509.00'],
 'tester_price': [u'\n\t\t            \xa349.00            \n\t\t        ']}
```

Comment: Just found out that it's better to overwrite loader variable with new one. Also do it only in case response has a `body` member. Editing code a bit.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `KeyError: 'loader'` on `loader = response.meta['loader']` using Scrapy 1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The css selector is do definitely work. The problem resides in the itemloader variable **l** in which you are saving in the meta dict, it points to the response from **firstRequest** callback, not to the **parseDescription1** callback in which this css selector can work

'div.price-breakdown div.price-excluding-tax span.price::text'

to solve this, just create a new itemloader **parseDescription1** or better load the item itself rather than its loader in the meta dict as follows...

```
    def firstRequest(self, response):

        l = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), response=response)

        l.add_css('nic_price', 'div.product-info p.product-price span[itemprop="price"]::text')

        yield Request('https://www.tester.co.uk/test-safe-pen-co-meter',
                  meta={'item': l.load_item()},
                  callback=self.parseDescription1)

    def parseDescription1(self, response):

        # Recover item
        item = response.meta['item']

        l = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), response=response)

        # Use just as before
        l.add_css('tester_price', 'div.price-breakdown div.price-excluding-tax span.price::text')

        l.add_value('nic_price', item['nic_price'])

        yield l.load_item()
```

Comment: The objective of my program is to generate an item by sourcing each attribute from a different  site. I have try to implement your code but then i yield the "l" and "l2" item loaders separately which results in 2 items.

Comment: I am investigating a workaround, any help is more than welcome.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this, one simple way is to load the item itself rather than its loader in the meta 


`meta={'item': l.load_item()},`


then, in **parseDescription1**


get the item from the meta dict and add **nic_price** as a value

`item = response.meta['item']`

`l.add_value('nic_price', item['nic_price'])`

Comment: I ended up passing items instead of item loaders. In each of the chained parsing functions, I added a property of the item.